# UWP Listview not selectable but clickable items

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I'd like to know if there's a way to make the ListView control items clickable when SelectionMode="None".  When I set it to "None" there is no visual feedback when the user clicks on the items in the List (Like there is when user select an item when SelectionMode="Single").

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `IsItemClickEnabled` to `True` on your `ListView` and handle `ItemClick` event instead.